# how to get a constant in java with class

Tags: java, reflection, dynamic, constants

basically I need to get a constant for a class however I have no instance of the object but only its class.
In PHP I would do `constant(XYZ);`
Is there a similar way of retrieving a constant in JAVA?

I need it to facilitate a dynamic getMethod call

```
Class parameterType = Class.forName(class_name);
object.setProperty(field name, field value, parameterType);
```

the set property method would then get the correct method and set the specified property, however I cant get a method which has int as parameter type without using Interger.TYPE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to get out. But it shouldn't be too difficult to show you an example.

Lets say you have a Class Foo with property bar.

```
Class Foo {
    private final String bar = "test";
    public String getBar() {return bar;}
}
```

Now to get this through reflection you would:

```
Class fooClass = Foo.class;
Object fooObj = fooClass.newInstance();
Method fooMethod = fooClass.getMethod("getBar");
String bar = (String) fooMethod.invoke(fooObj);
```

Now you will get value of method getBar() in bar variable

Answer (score 41):

You might look for sth. like 
 
`Foo.class.getDeclaredField("THIS_IS_MY_CONST").get(null);`

or

`Class.forName("Foo").getDeclaredField("THIS_IS_MY_CONST").get(null);`

(thanks [f-o-o](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1464389/f-o-o))

Gets the value of a String constant (THIS_IS_MY_CONST) in class Foo.

Update 
use `null` as argument for `get` thanks [acdcjunior](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1850609/acdcjunior)

Comment: Note that the `String.class` argument passed to the `Field#get(Object)` method is moot for static fields - per the javadoc:

> If the underlying field is a static field, the obj argument is ignored; it may be null.

So the argument does not imply that the field value will be a String and could be null.

Comment: Since it is a `static` field, `Foo.class.getDeclaredField("MY_CONST").get(null);` is the proper way to get its value. (The `String.class` argument in the answer is ignored and actually misleading.)

Comment: What if you don't know what Foo is? I think Class.forName("Foo") would be more ideal.

Answer (score 2):

If this constant is metadata about the class, I'd do this with [annotations](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html):

First step, declare the annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@interface Abc {
    String value(); 
}
```

Step two, annotate your class:

```
@Abc("Hello, annotations!")
class Zomg {

}
```

Step three, retrieve the value:

```
String className = "com.example.Zomg";
Class<?> klass = Class.forName(className);
Abc annotation = klass.getAnnotation(Abc.class);
String abcValue = annotation.value();
System.out.printf("Abc annotation value for class %s: %s%n", className, abcValue);
```

Output is:

```
Abc annotation value: Hello, annotations!
```

Comment: It does not answer to the OP question, but the "You aren't gonna need it" approach is interesting.

Answer (score 1):

To get private constant like:

```
private static final String BAR = "test";
```

you need to set it accessible first:

```
Field barField = Foo.class.getDeclaredField("BAR");
barField.setAccessible(true);
String bar = (String) barField.get(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand what you need, but did you try with final static attributes and static methods?

Final means that it can't be changed once set, so you get a constant.
Static means it's accessible even if there aren't any objects of the class.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to actually load or initialize the class, [ClassGraph](https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph/) can do this:

```
String fieldVal;
try (ScanResult scanResult =
        new ClassGraph().whitelistClasses(className).enableFieldInfo().scan()) {
    fieldVal = (String) scanResult.getClassInfo(className).getFieldInfo("s")
            .getConstantInitializerValue();
}
```

N.B. this works only for *constant initializer values* (values that can be computed without object instantiation, with the exception of `String`), assigned to *static final fields*. The compiler can produce a constant at compiletime for simple arithmetic and simple string concatenation.

(disclaimer, I am the author of ClassGraph)

Simply using reflection to access static fields is simpler, if you don't mind loading the class, as given in this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4076792/3950982