# Using reflection to get the initialization value of a field

Tags: java, reflection, initialization, field

```java
public class MyClass {
    private String s = "foo";
}
```

Is it possible to get `"foo"` using reflection without having to instantiate a new `MyClass`?

```java
Field field = MyClass.class.getDeclaredField("s");
// -- ideally: --
// Object initializationValue = field.getInitializationValue();
// assert initializationValue.equals("foo");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initialization statements like you have shown are actually moved into the constructor of the class, by the compiler. You need to actually instantiate a class in order for them to be executed. This is all behind the scenes of course. But in answer to your question, no, you cannot, not with reflection anyway.

But you could possibly determine those field values with static analysis tools like Soot, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible without "cheating".

One cheat might be to write (or generate) a class that creates a new `MyClass` instance, and uses reflection to dig out the value you want and write it to stdout.  Then you launch a child JVM to run that class, and read it in the current on.

Net result - you gotten the value without instantiating `MyClass` *in the current JVM*.

Another cheat would be to use a bytecode library to read the bytecodes from the `MyClass` ".class" file and *simulate* the execution of the `MyClass` initializer in the context of the current JVM.

Answer (score 1):

[ClassGraph](https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph/) can do this:

```
String clsName = "com.xyz.MyClass";
String s;
try (ScanResult scanResult =
        new ClassGraph().whitelistClasses(clsName).enableFieldInfo().scan()) {
    s = (String) scanResult.getClassInfo(clsName).getFieldInfo("s")
            .getConstantInitializerValue();
}
```

N.B. this works only for *constant initializer values* (values that can be computed without object instantiation, with the exception of `String`), assigned to *static final fields*. The compiler can produce a constant at compiletime for simple arithmetic and simple string concatenation.

(disclaimer, I am the author of ClassGraph)

If you don't mind loading the class, you can also simply use reflection to access static fields: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4076792/3950982